# Url rewriting with IIS 6 and MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis-6, isapi-rewrite

I have a url that can look like

```
domain.com/f1/v1/f2/v2/f3/v3/f4/v4/f5/v5/f6/v6
```

with variations of lesser counts such as

```
domain.com/f1/v1/f2/v2/f3/v3/f4/v4/f5/v5
domain.com/f1/v1/f2/v2/f3/v3/f4/v4
domain.com/f1/v1/f2/v2/f3/v3
domain.com/f1/v1/f2/v2
domain.com/f1/v1
```

how can i build a rewrite rule that will construct the following

```
domain.com/models?f1=v1&f2=v2...f6=v6
```

this website is an IIS 6 MVC 3 application using Helicon Isapi_Rewrite for url rewrites.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Helicon, but IIRF includes examples for transforming query-string params into url path segments, and vice versa.   You may be able to take those examples and apply them to Helicon, or just use IIRF. http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/1ccbf1ec-0984-49d9-9ab0-63eab3ff9c63.htm

Comment: why don't you use mvc's built in URL routing engine?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a set of rules each rule will process 1 pair, 2 pairs, 3 pairs of paraters...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# rule for one pair of parameters
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /models?$1=$2 [NC,L]

# rule for two pairs of parameters
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /models?$1=$2&$3=$4 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This approach works, however, you are limited to $1-$9.  I came up with a solution using a map file.  See answer.

Comment: I provided you with a solution for $1-$9 problem, see a comment

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution using a map.  The main problem I had was exceeding the $1-$9 limitation on placeholders.

```
RewriteMap filtermap txt:content/maps/filtermap.txt [NC]

RewriteCond ${filtermap:$6|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND  [NC]
RewriteRule ^models/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)   /models/?${filtermap:$1}&${filtermap:$2}&${filtermap:$3}&${filtermap:$4}&${filtermap:$5}&${filtermap:$6} [NC,L]

RewriteCond ${filtermap:$5|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND  [NC]
RewriteRule ^models/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)                 /models/?${filtermap:$1}&${filtermap:$2}&${filtermap:$3}&${filtermap:$4}&${filtermap:$5} [NC,L]

RewriteCond ${filtermap:$4|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND  [NC]
RewriteRule ^models/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)                               /models/?${filtermap:$1}&${filtermap:$2}&${filtermap:$3}&${filtermap:$4} [NC,L]

RewriteCond ${filtermap:$3|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND  [NC]
RewriteRule ^models/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)                                             /models/?${filtermap:$1}&${filtermap:$2}&${filtermap:$3} [NC,L]

RewriteCond ${filtermap:$2|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND  [NC]
RewriteRule ^models/([^/]*/[^/]*)/([^/]*/[^/]*)                                                           /models/?${filtermap:$1}&${filtermap:$2} [NC,L]

RewriteCond ${filtermap:$1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND  [NC]
RewriteRule ^models/([^/]*/[^/]*)                                                                         /models/?${filtermap:$1} [NC,L]
```

Its not super pretty but it does work.  The filter map looks like this

```
    p1/v1  p1=v1
    p2/v2  p2=v2
...
```

This is not an ideal solution if your combinations of p1/v1 are unlimited, but mine are finite so its pretty easy to manage.

Comment: you may go further $9 and use $$10-$$99 values in ISAPI_Rewrite 3